# Slide a hidden bootstrap card from right to left on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I have a bootstrap4 `card' which is hidden and I want to display it with slide right to left slow animation on button click. Below is the markup

```
 <div class="card" id="setup" style="display:none;">
 <div class="card-header">Settings</div>
 <div class="card-body">
 Setup
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Below is click event

```
 $("#Finalize").click(function () {
  $('#setup).show();
  $("#setup").animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow');
  });
```

With the above jquery code, I am just able to display the card, its animation effect is not working? What's wrong and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```js
 $(function(){
 $("#Finalize").click(function () {
  $(".cardcontainer").show();
  var left = $('#card').offset().left;


$("#card").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");

 
  });
  });
```

```css
.cardcontainer{
  position:relative;
  height: 220px;
display:none
}
.card{
    position:absolute !important;
    width:200px;
    right:0px;
   
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="cardcontainer">
 <div class="card" id="card">
 <div class="card-header">Settings</div>
 <div class="card-body">
 Setup
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>

<div>
  <a id="Finalize" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the html:

```
<div class="card animatable" id="setup" style="display: none;">
  <div class="card-header">Settings</div>
    <div class="card-body">
     Setup
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the CSS (we need to define a width for the card. I just put 500px, you can make it however big you want it obviously)

```
#setup {
  width: 500px;
}
```

And here is the javascript.

```
$("#Finalize").click(function () {

  if ($('#setup').hasClass('animatable')) {
    $('#setup').show();
    $('#setup').css('margin-left', $(window).width());
    $("#setup").animate({ right: "+=" + $(window).width()}, 'slow'); 
    $('#setup').removeClass('animatable');
  }
});
```

***Note*** I know you said you didn't want a margin. According to the HTML code you posted, the card will appear on the left side of the screen with the DOM loads. So if you run the animation, it will fly off the screen because it's going to move to the left when it's already placed at the left. So we need to move it to the right, hence my margin-left. Now if you ***absolutely*** cannot have a margin, you can give the card an absolute position, and just `left` it over to the right side of the screen. Also, we need to give it a width so that the card won't crumple up when we move it to the right side of the screen.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I need the card to move from right to left with no margin at either side..Please suggest..Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, let me edit this answer then. Is it suppose to slide all the way from the right side to the left side?